# How to change class name for active link using php and HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I Have created a web site having a navigation menu. The web page is created in CodeIgniter. I want to change the colour of an active page link to another.

I have tried some JS on the header page. First, I have tried multiple unordered lists. That was not working, and now I only kept the unordered list for navigation menu elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#mainav ul li').click(function(){
                          console.log('find');
                          $(this).addClass("active");
                        });
                      });
        </script>
```

Here mainav is the id of `<nav>` in header

**php file**

```
<nav id="mainav" class="fl_right">
                    <ul class="clear" id="navs">

                    <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in') || $this->session->userdata('verify'))  :?>
                          <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <?php endif ;?>
                    <?php if( $this->session->userdata('verify')):?>
                        <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>details/<?php echo $this->session->userdata('patient_id');?>" >Details</a></li>
                        <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>history/<?php echo $this->session->userdata('patient_id');?>">Consulting History</a></li>
                    <?php endif ;?>
                    <?php if( !$this->session->userdata('verify') && !$this->session->userdata('logged_in')):?>
                        <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>register">Register</a></li>
                        <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>print">Patient Login</a></li>
                        <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>login">Login</a></li>
                    <?php endif ;?>
                    <?php if( $this->session->userdata('logged_in')):?>
                    <li ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>doctor" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>list">List</a></li>
                    <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>list">Medicine</a></li>
                    <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>search">Patient</a></li>
                    <li ><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>logout">Logout</a></li>
                    <?php endif ;?>
                    <?php if( $this->session->userdata('verify')):?>
                    <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>logout">Logout</a></li><?php endif;?>
                    </ul>

                  </nav>
```

I need to identify which page is active now. That is to change the colour of an active link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<a class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="search"){echo "active";}?>"
```

**Explanation:**

It will get the segment of url like: **abc.com/search**

here `search` is the `segment(1)` so if the `segment(1)` value is equal to the hard coded `"search"` then it will add the active class.